# Android BroadcastReceiver does not receive intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Here is my sender in one app:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
intent.setAction("my.pack.SET_DONE");
intent.putExtra("name", "PWM");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And here is my receiver in the other app:

```
private Object mySyncObj = new Object();
private AtomicBoolean mySetDone = new AtomicBoolean(false);
static private MyBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "action = " + action );

            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("my.pack.SET_DONE")){
                synchronized (mySyncObj) {
                    mySetDone.set(true);
                    mySyncObj.notify();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The receiver is registered dynamically

```
mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("my.pack.SET_DONE");
mIntentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
ctx.registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
mySetDone.set(false);
// do something and then wait for the broadcast
synchronized (mySyncObj) {
        try {
            while(!mySetDone.get()) {
                mySyncObj.wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
    }
```

From logcat, I can see that the broadcasting the intent is okay but I never see the log in onReceive().

Comment: Where are you registering your receiver? If it's inside an activity it has to be active for it to receive the intent. If not you need to register your receiver inside the `Manifest`. Describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: if everything is OK, you should restart your phone and try again!

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

getIntent to receive the intent getExtra or GetStringExtra to take the .... with "name" key 
then you need to

```
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: does it help ...?

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever initialize `mReceiver` with `new MyBroadcastReceiver()`?